# WebSphere 9.0 is out of sync

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I'm running WebSphere 9.0 (WAS) with eclipse and  when I run the ear in the debug's pespective, I note that a out of sync. The steps are different the code line. I builded the project and I deploy severals time and this behaver persist. Does anyone have any idea? It's look like a cache, but I don't know where.

Comment: What methods are you using to build and deploy the application?  Are you building/deploying from an Eclipse WTP project?   Or are you using Maven or some other technique? Are you able to make other small changes to your application and notice them running the deployed app (e.g. inserting a println)?

Comment: I'm building using Maven. It's difficult to explaIn, but the error is in runtime and it is in the WAS excution. It's a wrong behaver and it happened I don't know why.

Comment: And do you have the project imported into Eclipse as a Maven project using a Maven builder?   It can get confusing if you attach the debugger with Eclipse building your app differently than the build you use to normally deploy.

Comment: Yes, I do. It's a Maven project and I using a Maven builder. It's crazy! It was running yesterday. Today failed. I did the deploy manually, I install the ear by WAS's console and I saw this out of sync in the thread runinng in the debug's pespective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this behavior is:

1. Check the ear's path.
2. Using the console's WAS to delete the application and install again.
3. Stop/start the WAS.

I lost so much time to find the problem and I think the WebSphere was out of sync.